# How to use Html.Telerik().Upload() control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using mvc3 application.

I want to use the Telerik control for file upload. I have found that one. But I am not able to upload a file with a size of 80 Mb. Does anyone have a solution for file size? Because I want to upload file whose size is more than 60 Mb.

If anyone would help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try customizing the `<httpRuntime>` element in your web.config file as explained in the [this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-uploading-large-files.html). You could increase the `maxRequestLength` and `executionTimeout` values.

Comment: i HAVE ALREADY DEFINE THIS I NWEB.CONFIG BUT DOES'NT GET THE SOLUTION .DO U HAVE ANY OTHER SOLUTION

Comment: Are you getting some specific error when you try to upload a larger file?

Comment: This article (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-troubleshooting.html) is specific for the Telerik ASP.NET MVC Extensions but covers the same properties and items that Darin mentioned. This should definitely be the way to go. Make sure you are increasing both to appropriate values.